# How to use a lock in threads

Tags: wpf, multithreading, locking

I'm using threads in WPF project.
And to control the threads flow, I'm using SpinLock in WPF.

However, I am faced on "This Lock is using another thread" error log at Runtime.( The original log is not english, so I translate to English. )

So, I think spinlock cannot used by threads.
I hope to know the way of using a lock in many threads.
Or I want to know another Lock can be used in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to post your code. The [documentation for `SpinLock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.spinlock(v=vs.110).aspx) says:

> All members of SpinLock are thread-safe and may be used from multiple threads concurrently.

Spin locks are only needed very rarely. You might like to investigate other locking primitives.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think i probably use atomic variable. However, I found C# doesn't support specific atomic variable. Many people wrote use Object than atomic variable. However, it is not general way, so I tryed to use spinlock instead of atomic.
Anyway, think you for your reply. I will try another way.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use threads, is the short answer. "Concurrency in C#" is the authoritative word in this field and covers the entire topic very comprehensively, I highly recommend you try to procure a copy. In the mean time I'll leave you with a quote from the opening chapter:

> Thread and BackgroundWorker types are not covered at all in this
>   book. They have had their time, and that time is over.